# How do you allow multiple people to push to github?

Tags: git, github

I would like to allow other members of our team to push to a GitHub repository, as there are other people I "trust" and dont want them to have to constantly bug me to do a push.

The only way I can see would be to add all our public keys into a single github repository. Is this the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 9):

You can add them as a collaborator to the repository. They number of collaborators is limited by the type of the account. (private/public repo and which kinds of accounts you all have)